# PHP and Test-driven development - Log class testing

Tags: php, tdd, phpunit, logging

I'm starting on TDD now. I've made some tests to write a log class.

How do I know if I've covered everything in the tests?

Am I missing any tests? The test "testShouldWriteANewLogEntry" uses date and time, did I test it right?

Do you have any suggestion about my tests?

log test

```
define('FILENAME', 'logs.txt');

class LogTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        if (file_exists(FILENAME)) {
            unlink(FILENAME);
        }
    }

    public function testShouldCreateANewLogFile()
    {
        $log = new Log(FILENAME);
        $this->assertFileExists(FILENAME);
    }

    public function testShouldWriteANewLogEntry()
    {
        $log = new Log(FILENAME);
        $log->write('This is a log message');
        $regExp = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a').' - This is a log message';
        $regExp = str_replace('/', '\/', $regExp);
        $this->assertRegExp('/^'.$regExp.'$/', file_get_contents(FILENAME));
    }

    public function testShouldWriteFiveLogEntries()
    {
        $log = new Log(FILENAME);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $log->write('#'.($i + 1).' message.');
        }
        $lines = count(file(FILENAME));
        $this->assertEquals($lines, 5);
    }
}
?>
```

Log class:

```
    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->_file = fopen($file, 'a');
    }

    public function write($message)
    {
        $dateTime = new DateTime();
        $message = $dateTime->format('m/d/Y h:i:s a').' - '.$message.PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($this->_file, $message);
    }
}
?>
```

I appreciate your help. It will be great to a TDD newby.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi thom. Welcome to StackOverflow. Good questions on this site include  a bit of code (as yours does), and ask a specific question about that code. For code reviews and discussions of "better ways," you may receive better answers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Thanks, are there any way to migrate my question? How? Thanks.

Comment: @thom: Flag it.  A moderate can move it for you.

Comment: Using constant for keeping filename in unit test is **terrible** practice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one thing that pops to mind, your second test is time-sensitive. If your machine is running a little slower, the test might fail, because it took a little longer to complete. But, you really want to see if the log entry put the datetime in correctly. To do this, pass in a fake DateTime interface to test it separate from the "get a time issue".

Maybe something like this:

```
interface DateRetriever {
    public function getCurrentDate($format);
}

public function testShouldWriteANewLogEntry()
{
    $log = new Log(FILENAME, new FakeDate());
    $log->write('This is a log message');
    $regExp = "2000-1-1".' - This is a log message';

    $regExp = str_replace('/', '\/', $regExp);
    $this->assertRegExp('/^'.$regExp.'$/', file_get_contents(FILENAME));
}

class RealDate implements DateRetriever {
    public function getCurrentDate($format) {
        return new DateTime()->format($format);
    }
}

class FakeDate implements DateRetriever {
    public function getCurrentDate($format) {
        return new DateTime("2000-1-1");
    }
}
```

And then the Log class:

```
public function __construct($file, DateRetriever $date)
{
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->_file = fopen($file, 'a');
}

public function write($message)
{
    $message = $this->date->getCurrentDate('m/d/Y h:i:s a').' - '.$message.PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($this->_file, $message);
}
```

Now, this is not exactly right, but pretty close. The point here is this: your test is really testing three things: 1) the way you get the current time 2) *where* your logs go 3) what goes in them/how they are formatted.

I only pulled out the way you get the current time, ideally, you will break out the way you save the log to the filesystem, maybe in a FileSystemManager. That way, you can test separately the "FileSystem" functionality, the "getCurrentDate" functionality, and your "what goes in a log" business rule. Now, you have a reusable file system class, and a reusable date class, both of which you are highly likely to need in the future.

I think one of TDD's best features is that it forces you to break apart concepts like that into independent *units* that can be then *unit tested*. Bob Martin has some very interesting ideas and posts about this sort of thing, [here](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to inject a date-time source as Steve suggested for such a small class, you can change your assertion to check the format for the time instead of the actual value.

```
$regExp = '/^[0-9\/: ]+(am|pm) - This is a log message$/';
```

With that there's also no need for the call to `str_replace()`.

You're also missing a test to verify that an existing file will be appended to rather than replaced.